# How to make the prev button remove activity from progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui

How can I make the prev button remove activity from progress:

```js
  var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Continue";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function removeElementsByClass(className) {
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        while (elements.length > 0) {
            elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
        }
    }

    function validateForm() {

        removeElementsByClass("validation-message");

        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByClassName("required");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false
                valid = false;
                if (y[i].classList.contains("signature")) {
                    alert("You should add you signature then click the button 'Add signature'")
                }
            }
        }

        //Validate Password
        var passwordField = x[currentTab].getElementsByClassName("passwordfield");
        if (passwordField.length) {
            if (passwordField[0].value.length < 8) {
                passwordField[0].className += " invalid";
                passwordField[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">Use 8 or more characters for your password.</span>');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (passwordField[0].value.length > 50) {
                passwordField[0].className += " invalid";
                passwordField[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">Use less than 50 characters for your password.</span>');
                valid = false;
            }
            if (passwordField[0].value != passwordField[1].value) {
                passwordField[1].className += " invalid";
                passwordField[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">The two passwords entered do not match. Please try again.</span>');
                valid = false;
            }
        }

        //Validate Password
        var all_alphanumric = x[currentTab].getElementsByClassName("alphanumric");
        if (all_alphanumric.length) {
            // var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var letterNumber = /^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i;
            for (j = 0; j < all_alphanumric.length; j++) {
                if (all_alphanumric[j].value.length && !(all_alphanumric[j].value.match(letterNumber))) {
                    all_alphanumric[j].className += " invalid";
                    all_alphanumric[j].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">Sorry, but only letters (Aa-Zz) and numbers (0-9) are allowed.</span>');
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Validate Mobile
        var all_mobiles = x[currentTab].getElementsByClassName("mobile_number");
        if (all_mobiles.length) {
            var letterNumber = /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
            for (k = 0; k < all_mobiles.length; k++) {
                if (all_mobiles[k].value.length && !(all_mobiles[k].value.match(letterNumber))) {
                    all_mobiles[k].className += " invalid";
                    all_mobiles[k].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">Please use a valid mobile number.</span>');
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Validate Email
        var all_mails = x[currentTab].getElementsByClassName("email_address");
        if (all_mails.length) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            for (s = 0; s < all_mails.length; s++) {
                if (all_mails[s].value.length && !(re.test(all_mails[s].value))) {
                    all_mails[s].className += " invalid";
                    all_mails[s].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span class="validation-message">Please use a valid email adress.</span>');
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }



        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("progtrckr-todo")[currentTab].className += " progtrckr-done";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("progtrckr-todo");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";

    }
```

```css
/* Start CSS FOR Multi Steps */

.multiSteps {
    margin: 90px 0;
}

.filter-multi {
    display: flex;
    width: 339px;
    height: 57px;
    margin: auto;
    outline: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filter-multi div {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-multi div h2 {
    color: #393C41;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
    letter-spacing: -1.16px;
}

.filter-multi .frist h2 {
    color: #fff;
}

.filter-multi .frist {
    background: #27BA5A;
    border-radius: 0 42px 42px 0;
}


/* Style the form */

#regForm {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 300px;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

#regForm input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

#regForm .tab {
    display: none;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

#regForm .step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Mark the active step: */

#regForm .step.active {
    opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

#regForm .step.finish {
    background-color: #27BA5A;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#regForm button {
    background-color: #27BA5A;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 41px;
    width: 156px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#regForm #prevBtn {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
}


/* Progress Tracker v2 */

ol.progtrckr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol.progtrckr li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="2"] li {
    width: 49%;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="3"] li {
    width: 33%;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="4"] li {
    width: 24%;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="5"] li {
    width: 19%;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
    color: silver;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #27BA5A;
    opacity: 1;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #27BA5A;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

ol.progtrckr li:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}

ol.progtrckr li:before {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
    content: "1";
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: -35px;
    left: 35%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
    color: #27BA5A;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #27BA5A;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "1";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "2";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "3";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "4";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "5";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: #27BA5A;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: -35px;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
}

ol.progtrckr {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

ol.progtrckr li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.9;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

ol.progtrckr li.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.bolts-step {
    display: none;
}


/* Mark the active step: */

.step.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.progtrckr span {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    width: 166px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 125px;
    bottom: -35px;
    color: #393C41;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
    width: max-content;
}

.progtrckr li {
    position: relative;
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "1";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "2";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "3";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "4";
}

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "5";
}

.multiSteps .title-regform {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold";
    letter-spacing: -1.98px;
    color: #393C41;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.multiSteps .grid-towCloman {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#regForm .form-erea label {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-R";
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #393C41;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    display: block;
}

#regForm .form-erea ::placeholder {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-R";
    color: #393C41;
}

#regForm .form-erea textarea,
#regForm .form-erea select,
#regForm .form-erea input {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D8D9D9;
    height: 41px;
}

#regForm .form-erea textarea {
    height: 133px;
}

#regForm .grid-diffCloman {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 8% 87%;
    grid-gap: 41px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#regForm .grid-diffCloman .form-erea select {
    text-align: center;
}

#regForm .form-erea select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 98%;
    background-position-y: 7px;
}

.grid-fourCloman {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.checkbox-form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.checkbox-form label {
    margin-left: 15px;
}


/* END CSS FOR Multi Steps */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Book Now</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Start Multi Steps-->
    <section class="multiSteps">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="filter-multi">
                        <div class="frist">
                            <h2>Australia</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="second">
                            <h2>International</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="progreess-multi-step">
                        <div class="ling-green"></div>
                        <ol class="progtrckr progress" data-progtrckr-steps="9">
                            <li class="step progtrckr-todo ">
                                <span>Shipment details</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" step progtrckr-todo ">
                                <span>Quote</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class=" step progtrckr-todo">
                                <span>Address</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="step progtrckr-todo">
                                <span>Summary</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="step progtrckr-todo">
                                <span>Payment</span>
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <form id="regForm" action="">


                        <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
                        <div class="tab" style="display: block;">
                            <h2 class="title-regform">01 Shipment details</h2>

                            <div class="grid-towCloman">
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for=" ">Pick-up Date</label>
                                    <input placeholder="Pick-up Date" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Pick-up Time</label>
                                    <input placeholder="12:00pm" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-towCloman">
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Service Type</label>
                                    <select name="" id="">
                                        <option value="Express">Express</option>
                                        <option value="Express">Express</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-diffCloman">
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Quantity</label>
                                    <select name="" id="">
                                        <option value="01">01</option>
                                        <option value="02">02</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Description</label>
                                    <textarea name="" id="" rows="10" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="grid-fourCloman">
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for=" ">Weight</label>
                                    <input placeholder="Weight (KG)" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Width</label>
                                    <input placeholder="Width (MM)" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for=" ">Length</label>
                                    <input placeholder="Length (MM)" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-erea">
                                    <label for="">Height</label>
                                    <input placeholder="Height (MM)" oninput="this.className = ''">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="grid-oneCloman">
                                <div class="checkbox-form">
                                    <input type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="">Save this information for next time</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab">
                            <h2 class="title-regform">02 Destination </h2>

                           
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab">
                            <h2 class="title-regform"> </h2>

                            <div class="form-erea"><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></div>
                            <div class="form-erea"><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></div>
                            <div class="form-erea"><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab">
                            <h2 class="title-regform"> </h2>

                            <div class="form-erea"><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''"></div>
                            <div class="form-erea"><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div style="overflow:auto;">
                            <div style="">
                                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Repeating your question several times will not get you an answer faster. I have edited that, but please don't do it anymore on the future. It comes across as either pushy or inattentive, neither of which you probably want. Also, please provide **minimal** working example of your problem and state **specifically** what your problem is. When you do that, I think you will see the community will be far better able to help you.

Comment: Your question is not clear, dunno what is activity ??